# using jquery, what is the best way to toggle a set of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, radio-button, toggle

i have a aspnet-mvc web page with a dropdown.  The choices in the dropdown are:

- Big
- Small

next to the dropdown i have a series of radio buttons

```
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","12",true)12  
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","24",false)24 
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","36",false)36 
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","48",false)48
```

i want to have it when i change the dropdown selection to Small, the list of radio buttons changes to

```
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","24",true)24
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","48",false)48
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","72",false)72
      @Html.RadioButton("quantity","96",false)96
```

and if you change the dropdown back to Big, it would change the radio buttons back to the original set above.

what is the best way of doing this?  should i have both sets of radio buttons on the page and hide the ones that are not associated with the selected item in the dropdown.  Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If you show the actual generated HTML rather than asp page, you will probably get more people able to offer you ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this working demo. I think this is what you are looking for.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Askk/)**

**Mark up**

```
<select>
    <option value="big">Big</option>
    <option value="small">Small</option>
</select>

<span id="big">
<input type="radio" value="24" checked/>12
<input type="radio" value="24" />24
<input type="radio" value="24" />36
<input type="radio" value="24" />48
</span>
<span id="small" style="display:none;">
<input type="radio" value="24" checked/>24
<input type="radio" value="24" />48
<input type="radio" value="24" />72
<input type="radio" value="24" />96
</span>
```

**Js**

```
$(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $("#big, #small").hide();
        $("#"+this.value).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: @jim - `toggle` will work if there are only 2 elements to show hide which is the case in this but it will not work for multiple containers to show/hide.

Comment: shankaer - yes, absolutely, basing my comment on the problem at hand - but prefect observation.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of having both sets on the page and hide the ones that are not associated with the selected item in the dropdown sounds about right, though I personally would turn things around, leave all eight radio buttons visible and get rid of the dropdown (size would be inferred from the selected radio).

Something like this:

```
Big:    ( ) 12  ( ) 24  ( ) 36  ( ) 48
Small:  ( ) 24  ( ) 48  (o) 72  ( ) 96
```

If you give them value like B-24, S-24, S-96, etc. splitting the pieces apart in your action method is trivial, you don't need to mess with javascript, and -more importantly- your end users will appreciate being able to select their choice with one click instead of three (one to open the dropdown, another to select the option, and a third to select the radio button).

Comment: i voted the other answer as correct as it gave the javascript code to do what i asked but i do appreciate your point in your answer.  I am now debating if i want to show both as you have displayed as i like the smaller # of clicks